# JS and CSS content not served by hosting Windows 10 1903 after upgrade

Tags: windows-10

After upgrading to Windows 1903 some local hosted server applications that worked before stopped doing this.

1. Swagger - I'm deploying my site with swagger support locally. Here are the Http 504 errors I got when loading the swagger's home page:

[image: Swagger loading error]

2. PGAdmin 4 - Postgre SQL management ide - browser app, hosted locally

[image: PGAdmin 4 error]

In other words, for any css or js files hosted by Windows 10 1903 OS I'm getting Http 504 errors.

What settings might have been broken by OS upgrade?

Here are some log extracts for swagger:

```
2019-08-30T11:02:35.3194425+03:00  [DBG] Connection id ""0HLPD414DKGML"" started. (1426b994)
2019-08-30T11:02:35.3196313+03:00 0HLPD414DKGML:00000001 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:6003/swagger/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js   (ca22a1cb)
2019-08-30T11:02:54.2232434+03:00  [DBG] Connection id ""0HLPD414DKGML"" reset. (3d6df208)
2019-08-30T11:02:54.2232772+03:00  [DBG] Connection id ""0HLPD414DKGML"" sending FIN because: ""An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"" (59510695)
2019-08-30T11:02:54.2233949+03:00  [DBG] Connection id ""0HLPD414DKGML"" disconnecting. (b29b9868)
2019-08-30T11:02:54.2235592+03:00 0HLPD414DKGML:00000001 [DBG] The file transmission was cancelled (b927d910)
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.StreamCopyOperation.CopyToAsync(Stream source, Stream destination, Nullable`1 count, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileContext.SendAsync()
2019-08-30T11:02:54.2236271+03:00 0HLPD414DKGML:00000001 [INF] Connection id ""0HLPD414DKGML"", Request id ""0HLPD414DKGML:00000001"": the application aborted the connection. (9f49aef1)
2019-08-30T11:02:54.2236533+03:00 0HLPD414DKGML:00000001 [INF] Sending file. Request path: '"/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"'. Physical path: '"N/A"' (27b0a520)
2019-08-30T11:02:54.2237020+03:00 0HLPD414DKGML:00000001 [INF] Request finished in 18904.0857ms 200 application/javascript (791a596a)
2019-08-30T11:02:54.2238709+03:00  [DBG] Connection id ""0HLPD414DKGML"" stopped. (056149f8)
```

Comment: Did you check your web servers logs as for what is causing the error? As it's a 504 it might indicate that the backend isn't working.

Comment: Added some logs.